# Restricted Boltzmann Machine (RBM) implementation in Tensorflow (TF) 2.x

Tags: unsupervised-learning

I‘m looking for a Python implementation of a Restricted Boltzmann Machine (RBM), e.g. applied to MNIST data as mentioned in „Elements of Statistical Learning“ Ch. 17, in Tensorflow **2.x**.

I‘m aware of code as linked [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/63744/71442). However, the model(s) are implemented in TF 1 and some layers are not supported any more (in TF2). Some links are also broken.

Can someone point me to a TF2 implementation of RBM or alternatively some implementation using `sklearn`?

Answer (score 0):

Following is an RBM implementation in Tensorflow 2.0.

As mentioned on the website:

> The Restricted Boltzmann Machine is a legacy machine learning model that is no longer used anywhere. This repository is of historical and educational value only. I have updated the code using the TensorFlow 2 to run on modern systems, but I will no longer maintain it.

https://github.com/meownoid/tensorflow-rbm